# “There need none. . .” in modern usage

Tags: grammar, archaic-language, early-modern-english

> There need none to be blamed. 
> <sub>Source: [*A Midsummer Night's Dream* (Act 5, Scene 1)](http://books.google.com/books?id=8h8WAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA106&ots=D_Q-vl8wZl&dq=%22There%20need%20none%20to%20be%20blamed.%22&pg=PA106#v=onepage&q=%22There%20need%20none%20to%20be%20blamed.%22&f=false)</sub>

Is this still possible in modern English?

For example: “There dared none to protest against him.”

Is this a version of the structure in “There lived a man in this city.”?

Comment: This is not a proofreading question, and is possibly an example of [Votes in Bad Faith](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/votes-in-bad-faith). If the downvotes are a reaction to the formatting, I recommend using the ‘Edit’ and/or ‘Comment’ tools instead of reaching for that down arrow.

Answer (score 2):

This structure would not occur in modern English. 
It would become:

> There's no need to blame anyone.
>
> Nobody dared protest against him.

Comment: *None* as a subject is still correct in modern English, though more formal and less common; e.g. *none dared protest against him*.